# QueryException in Connection.php line 662: : Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'content' cannot be null

Tags: laravel-5.1

### I use laravel 5.1, what can do with this error?

```
**strong text**in Connection.php line 662
at Connection->runQueryCallback('insert into `statuses` (`content`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?)', array(null, '1', '2017-02-04 14:36:46', '2017-02-04 14:36:46'), object(Closure)) in Connection.php line 618
at Connection->run('insert into `statuses` (`content`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?)', array(null, '1', '2017-02-04 14:36:46', '2017-02-04 14:36:46'), object(Closure)) in Connection.php line 391
at Connection->statement('insert into `statuses` (`content`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?)', array(null, '1', '2017-02-04 14:36:46', '2017-02-04 14:36:46')) in Connection.php line 347
at Connection->insert('insert into `statuses` (`content`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?)', array(null, '1', '2017-02-04 14:36:46', '2017-02-04 14:36:46')) in Processor.php line 32
at Processor->processInsertGetId(object(Builder), 'insert into `statuses` (`content`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?)', array(null, '1', '2017-02-04 14:36:46', '2017-02-04 14:36:46'), 'id') in Builder.php line 1843
at Builder->insertGetId(array(null, '1', '2017-02-04 14:36:46', '2017-02-04 14:36:46'), 'id')
at call_user_func_array(array(object(Builder), 'insertGetId'), array(array('content' => null, 'user_id' => '1', 'updated_at' => '2017-02-04 14:36:46', 'created_at' => '2017-02-04 14:36:46'), 'id')) in Builder.php line 1015
at Builder->__call('insertGetId', array(array('content' => null, 'user_id' => '1', 'updated_at' => '2017-02-04 14:36:46', 'created_at' => '2017-02-04 14:36:46'), 'id')) in Model.php line 1592
at Model->insertAndSetId(object(Builder), array('content' => null, 'user_id' => '1', 'updated_at' => '2017-02-04 14:36:46', 'created_at' => '2017-02-04 14:36:46')) in Model.php line 1561
at Model->performInsert(object(Builder), array()) in Model.php line 1452
at Model->save() in HasOneOrMany.php line 317
at HasOneOrMany->create(array('content' => null)) in StatusesController.php line 34
at StatusesController->store(object(Request))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StatusesController), 'store'), array(object(Request))) in Controller.php line 256
at Controller->callAction('store', array(object(Request))) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 164
at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(StatusesController), object(Route), 'store') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 112
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Authenticate.php line 45
at Authenticate->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(Authenticate), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 114
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(StatusesController), object(Route), object(Request), 'store') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 67
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\StatusesController', 'store') in Route.php line 203
at Route->runWithCustomDispatcher(object(Request)) in Route.php line 134
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 708
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 710
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 673
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 635
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 236
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 50
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 62
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 122
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 87
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
at require_once('/var/www/sample/public/index.php') in server.php line 21
```

Comment: Please format your error correctly, an ugly wall of text isn't great to look at. Additionally please show us the code that is generating this error for you

Comment: Well issue is on the error message "Column 'content' cannot be null" you are passing null as "content" `'insert into statuses (content, user_id, updated_at, created_at) values (?, ?, ?, ?)', array(null, '1', '2017-02-04 14:36:46', '2017-02-04 14:36:46')`. add `nullable()` to you content field on migration